# Html Select with checkboxes and multiple columns

Tags: jquery, html

Does somebody knows a jquery script to make html select options with checkboxes and multiple columns?

Something similar to this http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/ but not so complicated and maybe with multiple columns?

Comment: Could you try to better explain the problem you're having?

Comment: why you dont use that one?

Comment: What exactly is "so complicated" about it? It doesn't look to be particularly complicated for what it does.

Comment: @nahum because i need one with columns

Comment: But wait, you want only the dropdown with checkboxes option, or do you need to transform a select into a drowpdown with checkboxes??

Comment: @nahum, if I understand, she wants a dropdown with checkbox items and multiple columns. I think what would make more sense than something so specific is a dropdown that handle item templates. I know the infragistics combo does this, but I'm not aware of any free ones that do.

Comment: @nahum yes, i need to transform a select into a drowpdown with checkboxes, and im searching for one with multiple columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the Infragistics igCombo control I mentioned in my comments, there's also the jQuery ComboBox Template (http://jqcmbx.codeplex.com/), which appears to have a template-based combo box. This should allow you to style the combo box items however you want, including multiple columns and checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can see [this one](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/07/14/ui-elements-search-box/)

It has a live demo and the source code.